# i've a contentVersionId for which i'm creating a content distribution but i'm receiving INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY,

Tags: contentversion

```
public static string getDocumetDistribution(Id contentVersionId){
         list <ContentDistribution> contentDist1 = [SELECT Id,ContentVersionId,DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ContentVersionId =: contentVersionId];
          ContentVersion version = [SELECT Id,Title,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion where Id=: contentVersionId limit 1];
         if(contentDist1.size() >0 ){
            System.debug('contentDist[0].DistributionPublicUrl  '+contentDist1[0].DistributionPublicUrl);
        return contentDist1[0].DistributionPublicUrl;
    }else{
       
        ContentDistribution conDis = new ContentDistribution();
        System.debug('Name');
        conDis.Name = version.Title;
        System.debug('Content');
        conDis.ContentVersionId = contentVersionId;
        conDis.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser= true;
        
        conDis.PreferencesLinkLatestVersion=true;
        conDis.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit=false;
       // conDis.PreferencesPasswordRequired=false;
        conDis.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload= true;
        insert conDis;
        list <ContentDistribution> contentDist = [select Id, ContentDownloadUrl, DistributionPublicUrl  from ContentDistribution where id=:conDis.Id];
        System.debug('contentDist[0].DistributionPublicUrl  '+contentDist[0].DistributionPublicUrl);
        return contentDist[0].DistributionPublicUrl ;//ContentDownloadUrl;
    }

    //String BASE_URL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    //return BASE_URL + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId='+contentVersionId;
    //return BASE_URL + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+version.ContentDocumentId;
}
```

Comment: The error occurs on `insert conDis;` ?

Comment: Yes and the visibility on the content version is V

Comment: did you check `Users (including users with the “View All Data” permission) can query only the files that they have access to. If the file is managed by a Content Library, the user must have “Deliver Content” enabled in the library permission definition and be a member of the library. If the file isn’t managed by a Content Library, the user must have the “Enable Creation of Content Deliveries for Salesforce Files” permission.`